# Rearranging skills on the action bar

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is there a way to move your skills around on your action bar? Everytime I try to move them it just tries to perform the action.

Comment: You probably have your action bars locked. Look in the menu for UI settings > Action bars > unlock them if you want to move skills. This used to be how it was done

Comment: Try holding SHIFT while moving.

Comment: @SAndokan that is the correct answer, I was going to post it as an answer until I saw your comment. Please post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try holding SHIFT while moving the skills.

Answer (score -2):

Hold <kbd>shift</kbd> and then click and drag the skill to another slot. If you want to remove one, hold <kbd>shift</kbd> and drag the skill to a empty spot on the screen.